# How to add OnChange each Option On the Dynamic Select Box

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

In My React Project Dynamically Added Options In the Select Box.

```
ComponentDidMount(){
   var status_id = document.getElementById('c_status').options;
 }
 Data.forEach( (option) => {
       status_id.add( new Option(option,option,true)),
  }):
```

> Const Data=['active','paused']; //constant array

```
 render() {
   return (<div><select id="c_status"></select></div>)
  }
```

My Question is select Box click to show values **active** and **paused**. 
How to  **OnChanged** using this options?

Comment: Read the forms section of react docs. There is even an example of onChange for <select> https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve but `option` tag doesn't have `onChange` event. But you can use `onChange` event on `select` tag.

```
 class Example extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        options: ['active', 'paused']
    }
  }
  onChange(e){
    console.log(this.state.options[e.target.selectedIndex])
  }
  render() {
    return <select onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)}>
      {this.state.options.map(el => <option key={el} value={el}>{el}</option>)}
    </select>;
  }
}
```

[`Worked example`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/98337/)